# iOS AFNetwokring: Network Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, web-services, afnetworking

What I want to accomplish is that add some raw json to a GET request and send it to server. But I always get one response:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x7fedb27e0d00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fedb24f86a0 "The network connection was lost.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=[URL REMOVED], NSErrorFailingURLKey=[URL REMOVED], _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}

Here is the CURL command which I want to implement:

```
curl.exe -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "API-Version: 1" -i -d '{ \"UserName\" : \"userName\", \"Password\": \"password\" }' -k https://my-url-here
```

**My Source Code:**

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"UserName":username, @"Password": password};

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[sharedInstance.base_url stringByAppendingFormat:@"/api/applicant/%@",applicant_id]]];
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
[securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

NSString *bodyString = [Utils dictToJson:dict];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"API-Version"];
[request setValue:@"nokeepalive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
[request setHTTPBody:[bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];


[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON responseObject: %@ ",responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}];

[operation start];
```

Comment: this is iOS 8 problem ', in here u need to increase the time out in server or else call to again web service in 2nd time

Comment: Same is happening on iOS 7.1 simulator

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for your question is.
Please check internet connection before API call.